# How would this React code look without React-hooks and with class components rather than function components(button sidebar)?

Tags: reactjs

I just studied React from some lessons, and there all the lessons were built on classes components and the usual this.setState, without hooks. How would this React code look without React-hooks and with class components rather than function components? The code itself implements left sidebar which crawls to the left after you press a button.

```
const Sidebar = ({onClick, show}) => (
  <div id="mySidebar" className={`sidebar ${show ? 'show' : ''}`}>
    <a href="#" className="closebtn" onClick={onClick}>×</a>
  </div>
)

const App = () => {
  const [show, toggle] = React.useState(false)
  const handleClick = () => toggle(!show)

  return (
    <main>
      <Sidebar show={show} onClick={handleClick}/>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Sidebar</button>
    </main>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'))
```

All code:
https://jsfiddle.net/964Lez30/12

Comment: ... Why not just look at pre-hooks tutorials to see how state is handled? `App` would be a normal class, and you'd set initial state in either the ctor or via an instance property, and `handleClick` would be a bound function that modified the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without hooks

Your sidebar component will look the same, it does no state management.

```
const Sidebar = ({onClick, show}) => (
  <div id="mySidebar" className={`sidebar ${show ? 'show' : ''}`}>
    <a href="#" className="closebtn" onClick={onClick}>×</a>
  </div>
)
```

Your App component would look like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     show: false
    }
  }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      show: !prevState.show
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const handleClick = () => this.toggle();
    return (
      <main>
        <Sidebar show={this.state.show} onClick={handleClick}/>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Sidebar</button>
      </main>
    )
  }
}
```

When you dig deeper and compare both the components, you can notice the only argument passed to useState is the initial state. Unlike `this.state`, the state here doesn’t have to be an object — although it can be if you want. The initial state argument is only used during the first render. `useState` returns a tuple pair: the current state value and a function that lets you update the state.

I'd prefer hooks to class components for various reasons - Hooks allow you to reuse stateful logic without changing your component hierarchy. Hooks let you split one component into smaller functions based on what pieces are related, rather than forcing you to split your code based on component life cycle methods.